# Youtube Livechat API is not finding the live chat

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

So I was trying to use the LiveChat API from youtube, At the end I got into using this post:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?access_token=MYACCESSTOKENHERE&part=snippet&messageText=lalala&liveChatId=0bksQfFVZW4
```

Now it tells me that it can't find the liveChatId, Any reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[liveChatId property](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages) is associated with liveBroadcast. So try making calls to any of the [liveBroadcast methods](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts) . A successful response includes the `liveChatId` property. Don't forget to specify '`snippet`' as the '`part`' parameter. Also, you'll be required to use [OAuth Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/authentication) when calling these methods.

Comment: From what I searched its the only to get the id, Apparently you can't get it for broadcasts that are not your own at this point. So I am accepting your answer